# Time Format("h a") not localized to french in Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, development-environment

I have try to localize the time format(AM/PM) in Xamarin.Android by using `SimpleDateFormat` like below code example :

**Code example:**

```
Calendar time = Calendar.GetInstance(Locale.Default);

string timeText = new SimpleDateFormat("h a", new Locale("fr")).Format(time.Time).ToLower();
```

But it will always localize only for English(9 am). Please suggest am I missed anythig to localize string. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked my answer? Any update?

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT Sorry for the late reply, i have tried your code example but still the time text "AM" was not localized as per specific region(France). Also,When i try to localize the chinese region time text "Am/PM" localized as per the region.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did wrong to create a new `Locale` for `fr`, to use given pattern and the default data format symbols for the given locale "France", you can for example code like this:

```
Android.Icu.Util.Calendar time = Android.Icu.Util.Calendar.GetInstance(Locale.Default);
var format = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a", Android.Icu.Util.ULocale.French);
var timetext = format.Format(time.Time);
```

For more information, you can refer to [SimpleDateFormat (String pattern, 
                Locale locale)](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat(java.lang.String, java.util.Locale)).

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer, I have tried your code snippet, it won't work. But the time text(Am/Pm) localized for chinese region.

Android.Icu.Util.Calendar time = Android.Icu.Util.Calendar.GetInstance(Locale.Default);
var format = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a", Android.Icu.Util.ULocale.Chinese);
var timetext = format.Format(time.Time);

Comment: @Siva, you mean this code works for Chinese but not for French?

Comment: @Siva, my fault, could you please try `var format = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a", Android.Icu.Util.ULocale.French);`. If you find this answer helpful, could you please mark this answer?

Comment: it seems the same code  var format = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a", Android.Icu.Util.ULocale.French), what you have mentioned earlier.

Comment: Still i have experiencing the same issue.

Comment: @Siva, using `var format = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a", Android.Icu.Util.ULocale.French)` should solve the problem, I can't find any other problem with the code sample...